# Показ окна с ошибкой по нажатию кнопки

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно добавить в дельфи 7 такую кнопку, чтобы нажимая на неё вылазило окно аналогичное ошибке. И после нажатия "ок" моё приложение закрывалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
var q:integer;
...
q := MessageDlg('Error!!!',mterror,[mbCancel,mbOk],0);
if(q=mrOk) then application.terminate;
```

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вас устроил.

Comment: Не получается. Он выдаёт как ошибку в коде

Comment: Думаю, можно было догадаться изменить кавычки " на '

Comment: Он выдаёт ошибку в самом начале кода

Comment: Так нагляднее

    if(MessageDlg('Error!!!',mterror,[mbCancel,mbOk],0) = mrOk) then application.terminate;